# Integration of Selenium Webdriver with Hudson - Unable to open the browser

Tags: hudson, webdriver

I have integrated my selenium Webdriver scripts (using TestNG) with Hudson. i invoked my job through ant . My problem is my scripts are not running successfully also the IE browser is not getting opened However Build is creating successfully.

Note - 
1) I am triggering build on Hudson from different machine on the same network with administrative access. 
2) I have used excel 2007 for developing the script ( data driven framework) however on Hudson server its open office.could that be the issue?

At this moment i am not using selenium grid .please provide any suggestion

Comment: Are you using hudson  master & slave ?

Comment: Yes.I am using Hudson master & slave.

Comment: Is the workspace content for Job created in slave & does it had the same workspace contents as in master?

Comment: Hi All,

Just to update: this problem is solved.

below are the details:
Put Internet driver in path
Run Browser Hub for remote exectution
java -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=0 -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role hub 

java -Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=0 -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register 

Refer following links:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs

-Fanindra

Comment: I had a similar problem where Selenium wouldn't open a browser if Jenkins ran a service and so I had to run a Jenkins slave as a foreground process in order for tests to work.

Comment: @Fanindra: Your question is still showing up in the Unanswered list. You should post your solution as an answer, then accept it, to show that you are not waiting for an answer from anybody else.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is because Hudson/Jenkins is running as a Windows service.   Recently, Microsoft changed services so that [they run on their own invisible desktop](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-ntservice-interactive.html).  This didn't used to be the case until a few years ago.  For this reason, even if you check "interact with desktop" , the desktop that is being referred to is invisble .

So, what you have to do is run Jenkins (not Hudson) as a service only for the master server.  For the Selenium tests, you need to run another slave Jenkins server as a foreground shell process and the selenium tests need to be launched from that Jenkins instance instead.

If you think [the instructions for setting up a slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines) are too hard, then you should know that it isn't required that you run as an official configured slave.  You can run as a separate slave (make sure port number is different).

Also, if you are running Grids and Nodes on Windows, you might like [these scripts I made](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5174433).